# which method should I be using?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
>>> class StrictList(list):
...     def __init__(self,content=None):
...         if not content:
...             self.content = []
...             self.type = None
...         else:
...             content = list(content)
...             cc = content[0].__class__
...             if l_any(lambda x: x.__class__ != cc, content):
...                 raise Exception("List items must be of the same type")
...             else:
...                 self.content = content
...                 self.type = cc
... 
>>> x = StrictList([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> x
[]
>>> x.content
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would like to be able to return the contents when calling `x` not `x.content`

Comment: I have edited to I is hopefully a bit clearer...

Comment: *Now* you have a question :-)

Comment: That Exception would be better off being a TypeException, too!

Comment: yeah, I was just writing it quickly to try out an idea... Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Please improve the title for SEO. There is no question right now

Comment: If I had known of a better title to give it, I would have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to subclass `list` but never call the list `__init__` method. Add this:

```
super(StrictList, self).__init__(content)
```

to add the items to self. There is no need to assign to `self.content`:

```
>>> class StrictList(list):
...     def __init__(self,content=None):
...         super(StrictList, self).__init__(content)
... 
>>> s = StrictList([1, 2, 3])
>>> len(s)
3
>>> s[0]
1
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Will accept when the time allows

Comment: Aaand for Python 3, you can simply do `super().__init__(content)`:)